# Datepicker of Boostrap for CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, bootstrap-datepicker

I need help to refactor this code with html or form helpers of cake:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="control-label">ÚLTIMO SERVICE</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This script works fine:

```js
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(['block' => true]); ?>

// <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input#date').datepicker({
    format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    changeYear: true
  });

});

<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd(); ?>
```

Comment: I make this with form helper. Then i had input and span elements like div atributes. https://jsfiddle.net/0qnvm7ks/1/

Comment: Have you looked at the FriendsOfCake BootstrapUI plugin?